# Routing IP to a VM Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, routing, rras

We are moving to a rental office.  Trying to configure a server.

The server runs Windows Server 2012R2.  There are two VM's.  One is a AD server, the other is a remote access server.  There are two networks.  The first is an external public IP connection provided by the building.  It is behind a firewall but all ports are open.  The second network is a local one to the office, 10.201.51.x.  I created a virtual switch for the internal network and gave all the servers static IP's.  Internal network works fine.

I would like to take all the traffic from the external connection with the public IP address and route it to the remote access server.  I used to do this with a cisco router but we don't have that here.

Is it possible to create a virtual switch that does this?  If not, is there a way to do this with Windows.  I have looked around but the docs on the web are more confusing than anything.  Is there a place that gives instructions for this in Windows?

Comment: Do you plan to plug in the cable coming from your ISP directly into the Server providing virtualization?

Comment: Yes the cable from the ISP is into NIC #1 and the local network is into NIC #2

Comment: I am not an expert on this but I guess you want to utilize an _external vSwitch_ to map your RAS server to NIC#1.

Answer (score 0):

To dedicate NIC #1 to your remote access server you should open "Virtual Switch Manager" -> "New virtual network switch" -> "External" -> "Create virtual switch".

On this new virtual switch: Give it a name, click External Network, select NIC #1 and uncheck "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" (When you do this remotely you will lose your connection).

Inside your VM Settings -> Network Adapter -> select your virtual switch. If you need to assign it to a specific MAC-address, if internetprovider requires this, click on + and in Advanced Features you can select Static and fill out the MAC-address.